# How to use GameManager to get GameOver() from another script?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to make a gameover-text show when the player is leaving the plane-area. In GameManager.cs I've written:

```
public void GameOver()
{
    gameOverText.gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

And in PlayerController.cs I've used the following code:

```
private GameManager gameManager;
```

and:

```
void Update()
{
    float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.right * speed * horizontalInput);
    playerRb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speed * verticalInput);

    if (transform.position.y < -4)
    {
        gameManager.GameOver();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't really work, and the console is giving me this message:

> Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs(8,25): warning CS0649: Field 'PlayerController.gameManager' is never assigned to, and will always have its default value null

I've already used the `OnTriggerEnter` (for powerups) and `OnCollisionEnter` (for enemies). How can I get the GameOver-text to show when the player leaves the "Plane"?

Comment: How do you expect a reference to your `GameManager` script instance will get populated into your `private GameManager gameManager` variable? Remember this variable will hold a value of "null" until you put something there, either by assigning it in your script, or exposing it as a field you can populate in the Inspector UI. So, what's your strategy for wiring up this value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*TLDR:* Add the `SerializeField` attribute to the `GameManager` variable in the `PlayerController`, then reference the desired `GameManager` instance through the inspector.

---

In the `PlayerController` class you have included a variable of the type `GameManager`, but you have not populated the variable with any instance of `GameManager`.

Populating variables and referencing can be achieved in a variety of ways, but one simple method I like in Unity is to use the inspector to manually populate variables. Here is one example of how to populate this variable with a reference to the specific instance of `GameManager`, through the inspector via the `SerializeField` attribute.

In `PlayerController` class:

```
[SerializeField] //added this attibute which will affect the `gameManager` variable
private GameManager gameManager;
```

By adding the `SerializeField` attribute the variable will be visible in the inspector, even though normally only public variables are shown in inspector. You can then drag the `GameManager` instance in your scene into this serialized variable on the `PlayerController`. Now when your scene starts up it will actually have a reference to a specific instance on the `GameManager` class, so it should be able to call functions etc.

---

edit: Note that the `SerializeField` attribute only works for certain types, I am assuming that your `GameManager` inherits from `Unity.Object` (or one of its children like `GameObject`, `Component`, etc). For more details on serialization through this attribute, [check out the official docs for SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html)

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this you would either want to make that a `public GameManager gameManager` or add a `[SerializeField]`above the variable and simply drag it to the slot to set it.

If you would like to keep it private you could either use a `Gameobject.Find();` or something like `FindObjectOfType()` to set that manager in `Start()`

After assigning your manager when you call `gameManager.GameOver()` you will no longer have a null value.

Answer (score 0):

Some developers hate singletons, but the canonical answer is to make a single long-lived class instance into a singleton, so there is one instance which can be accessed from any other script.

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static GameManager Instance { get; private set; }

    void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }
}
```

Then any other script can call its public methods as so:

```
GameManager.Instance.DoSomething();
```

To simplify this logic so other classes can be singletons easily, use the following helper (this interesting inheritance pattern is called the [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)):

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : Singleton<T> // or where T : MonoBehaviour, depending on which types of subclass you need
{
    public static T Instance { get; private set; }

    protected void Awake()
    {
        Instance = (T)this;
    }
}

public class GameManager : Singleton<GameManager>
{
    protected new void Awake()
    {
        base.Awake();
        // do other needed init
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the `{ get; private set; }` doing in this example?

Comment: @AmyGamble It serves as the field that stores the long lived instance, but also as the public function that allows other logic to get the reference to the instance by calling `GameManager.Instance`. A simple `public static T Instance;` would work the same way but would have the non-ideal characteristic of letting other classes assign to the value, for example setting the instance to null.